# Button height inconsistency (cross-browser)

Tags: button, cross-browser, css

I'm having a problem whilst setting the height of a button. Basically I can't manage to have it cross-browser. With Firefox, it is higher than *normal*, without any reason.

Here it's a screenshot (Firefox, Safari and Opera, in this order):

[image: Initial]

And here the code: http://jsfiddle.net/TMUnS/2/

I also tried adding some specific declarations I found on the web, but actually they just reduced the height a bit, but still, they aren't the same (in the same order):

[image: Second try]

And here the code: http://jsfiddle.net/TMUnS/4/.

How could I fix this?

Comment: Well, this just happens and this question has been asked endlessly. Inputs and pixel perfection don't mix well most of the time due to browser inconsistencies. I suggest you start with something like **normalize.css** and then adjust from there.

Comment: I already have a reset, but it doesn't seem to reset this stuff.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firefox has this funny thing called `-moz-focus-inner`. I'm not totally sure what it's for, I just know that you sometimes need to do this to get buttons to behave:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner {
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}
```

That might be what you need. You can see the difference here (in Firefox): http://jsfiddle.net/TMUnS/9/

Comment: Well, actually I set this property, but I forgot to add the `padding: 0` part, so it didn't work properly! But now I've a new problem, that you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/TMUnS/12/. The buttons have the same height, but in Firefox it isn't vertically okay.

Comment: I don't see your problem clearly. Some things to note: 1) The demo you just linked to does not contain the `-moz-focus-inner` code 2) You did not specify a `font-family`. I get different default fonts in Chrome VS Firefox, so different rendering. 3) `<button>` is often easier to style than `<input>` (*and* can contain HTML), I'd suggest using it if possible.

Comment: I guess it's fond depending. Thanks for the tip. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature set in Firefox which limits the line-height of buttons. It sets a default line height for buttons - http://www.cssnewbie.com/input-button-line-height-bug/. I would try using a fixed height for the buttons and playing around with the padding.

Comment: Yeah, this is the best you can do. Fixed height and same line-height to center the text vertically. I've used this technique with search buttons that touch the text input, so it's important that it looks consistent in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a CSS-Reset ?
A CSS-Reset normalizes the CSS for the Browsers.

Try this YUI reset:
[YUI CSS RESET](http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.4.1/build/cssreset/cssreset-min.css)