# Button vs. Clickable Div in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, performance

In HTML is it better to use a button or a clickable div?
Either way I'm going to use jQuery to handle the event of the click, but I'm wondering if there are advantages/disadvantages to using one over the other. Such as execution speed, loading speed, etc.

```
<button id="temp">Click</button>
```

vs.

```
<div id="temp">Click</div>
```

The code I'm using to handle the click event looks like this,

```
$("#temp").click(function(){
//Event details here
};
```

I understand that the button element is already pre-styled to look like a button and that (on windows) if you you press the enter key after a button has been selected (via click) the button will reactivate as if it were clicked again, but that is both of those factors aren't very important  to  me.

Comment: This is to broad, for buttons you use buttons, but sometimes you have a div container with some content and images that need a click event to show a popup or something simular. You have to see it in its context to use it.

Comment: You need to separate between what is possible in the browser, with what is semantically correct. If you need a button, use a button. `div` doesn't have any semantic value, its just a container.

Comment: Depends if you want to be semantically correct or not. I would say though that using elements that are meant to be clicked is probably the best way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<button>` has some inbuilt things that you may like, but also has some styling restrictions that not apply to `<div>`.

`<button>` can be focused, where `<div>` has to have `tabindex` attribute to make focus work.
Pressing it can submit a form if configurated for ex. has built in `onclick` handler: `<button onclick="submit()">`

Usage of `<button>` applies to HTML5 document specification which puts divs in place of containers elevating role of contextual elements like `<footer>`, `<section>` and `<button>`.

In short I always use `<div>`s as can style it how I need and program them how I like, am not fancying predefined behaviours as they can vary on different browsers :)

Comment: What are the styling restrictions of `<button>` over `<div>`? Also a div can have a `onclick` attribute too.

Comment: 10 seconds of search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186760/button-height-inconsistency-cross-browser

Comment: That's not restrictions, that's one cross browser issue. Not really a good reason to go against the HTML semantics which will affect the accessibility of the content unless extra work is done.

Comment: @gillesc feel free to make your life harder, while I chill with `<div>`s

Answer (score 10):

Don't use `<div>` tags to make clickable elements. Use `<a>` or `<button>` elements. This enables browsers with JavaScript disabled to interact with them as expected. Even if your functionality requires JavaScript and there is no reasonable default behaviour you can assign to an `<a>`, use it regardless - it conveys "clickable" semantics.

In general, choose the tag that most closely describes the function of its content, not the appearance of its content, and avoid unnecessary `<div>` tags, lest your documents suffer from divitis.

http://csscreator.com/divitis

Comment: Anchors should not be used as buttons. This violates principles of accessibility.